# How to set an ndb keyProperty

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm having some trouble understanding how entities and keys work in Google App Engine NDB.

I have a `post` entity and a `user` entity. How do I set the `user_key` on `post` to `user`?

In the interactive console, I have this so far:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from app.lib.posts import Post
from app.lib.users import User
from random import shuffle

users = User.query()
posts = Post.query().fetch()

for post in posts:
  post.user_key = shuffle(users)[0]
  post.put()
```

I'm just trying to set up some seed data for development. I know this probably isn't the ideal way to set things, but my first question is:

1. How do I get a key from an entity (the reverse is described in the docs)
2. How do I set associations in ndb?

Comment: Take a look here. This helped me a lot
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711077/how-to-structure-movies-database-and-user-choices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
post.user_key = shuffle(users)[0].key
```

Comment: I thought I tried this. But I might have tried it without fetching the query first. Sanity restored, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps to understand the NDB. I had the same questions with you.

```
class Person(ndb.Expando):
    pass

class Favourite(ndb.Expando):       
    pass

class Picture(ndb.Expando):
    pass

person  = Person()
person.put()
picture = Picture()
picture.put()
fav = Favourite(parent=person.key,
        person=person.key,
        picture=picture.key
        )
fav.put()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify that shuffle works in this case, as User.query() returns an iter, not a list. (You can convert it to a list using shuffle( [ x for x in users ] ). Beware, this list could be looong.
2. NDB has some really wired behavior sometimes, so id recommend you dont store an NDB-Key, but its serialized string, which is also compatible to ext.db: post.user_key = shuffle( [ x for x in users ] ).key.urlsafe()
3. You could use KeyProperty for associations. If you need a more fine-graned control over your relations, you must implement them yourself.
   See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#structured

Comment: I should have posted my classes too. I *am* using KeyProperty to define user_key. Associations still seem funky to me though.